# Hide Sidebar and call method declared in other vue page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

actually I am learning some VueJS and I take a look to some free template online. I faced with https://github.com/creativetimofficial/vue-paper-dashboard
and I realize that it is pretty good example, for understand some concepts.

I see that it have a side bar and now I am asking myself who to implement how to hide this side bar.
I want to implement a button for hide the sideBar. But I do know how to implement that.

I take a look in internet how to implement something like that. e.g. https://dmitripavlutin.com/vue-show-hide-elements/

but does not works.

I would implement that in /components/SidebarPlugin/SideBar.vue

```
 <div
    class="sidebar"
    :data-background-color="backgroundColor"
    :data-active-color="activeColor"
    v-show="isVisible"
   
  >
[...]

  data() {
    return {
      isVisible: true,
      
    }
  }
[...] 

  methods {
 
    hideSideBar() {

         this.isVisible = !this.isVisible;

    }
```

which will leave the file

```
<template>
  <div

    v-show="isVisible"
    class="sidebar"
    :data-background-color="backgroundColor"
    :data-active-color="activeColor"
  >
  v-show="isVisible"
    <!--
            Tip 1: you can change the color of the sidebar's background using: data-background-color="white | black | darkblue"
            Tip 2: you can change the color of the active button using the data-active-color="primary | info | success | warning | danger"
        -->
    <!-- -->
    <div class="sidebar-wrapper" id="style-3">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="#" class="simple-text">
          <div class="logo-img">
            <img src="@/assets/img/vue-logo.png" alt="" />
          </div>
          {{ title }}
        </a>
      </div>
      <slot> </slot>
      <ul class="nav">
        <!--By default vue-router adds an active class to each route link. This way the links are colored when clicked-->
        <slot name="links">
          <sidebar-link
            v-for="(link, index) in sidebarLinks"
            :key="index"
            :to="link.path"
            :name="link.name"
            :icon="link.icon"
          >
          </sidebar-link>
        </slot>
      </ul>
      <moving-arrow :move-y="arrowMovePx"> </moving-arrow>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import MovingArrow from "./MovingArrow.vue";
import SidebarLink from "./SidebarLink";
export default {
  props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      default: "Paper Dashboard",
    },
    backgroundColor: {
      type: String,
      default: "black",
      validator: (value) => {
        let acceptedValues = ["white", "black", "darkblue"];
        return acceptedValues.indexOf(value) !== -1;
      },
    },
    activeColor: {
      type: String,
      default: "success",
      validator: (value) => {
        let acceptedValues = [
          "primary",
          "info",
          "success",
          "warning",
          "danger",
        ];
        return acceptedValues.indexOf(value) !== -1;
      },
    },
    sidebarLinks: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [],
    },
    autoClose: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
    },
  },
  provide() {
    return {
      autoClose: this.autoClose,
      addLink: this.addLink,
      removeLink: this.removeLink,
    };
  },
  components: {
    MovingArrow,
    SidebarLink,
  },
  computed: {
    /**
     * Styles to animate the arrow near the current active sidebar link
     * @returns {{transform: string}}
     */
    arrowMovePx() {
      return this.linkHeight * this.activeLinkIndex;
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      linkHeight: 65,
      activeLinkIndex: 0,
      windowWidth: 0,
      isWindows: false,
      hasAutoHeight: false,
      links: [],
      isVisible: true,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    findActiveLink() {
      this.links.forEach((link, index) => {
        if (link.isActive()) {
          this.activeLinkIndex = index;
        }
      });
    },
    addLink(link) {
      const index = this.$slots.links.indexOf(link.$vnode);
      this.links.splice(index, 0, link);
    },
    removeLink(link) {
      const index = this.links.indexOf(link);
      if (index > -1) {
        this.links.splice(index, 1);
      }
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$watch("$route", this.findActiveLink, {
      immediate: true,
    });
  },
  hideSideBar() {
    this.isVisible = !this.isVisible;

  },
};
</script>
<style></style>
```

[..]
and call that in a button on /pages/Dashboard.vue

```
[...]
  <v-button id="click"  @click="hideSideBar()" > Hide sideBar </v-button>
[...]
```

and will be leaving the file Dashboard.vue like:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!--Stats cards-->
    <div class="row">
      <div
        class="col-md-6 col-xl-3"
        v-for="stats in statsCards"
        :key="stats.title"
      >
        <stats-card>
          <div
            class="icon-big text-center"
            :class="`icon-${stats.type}`"
            slot="header"
          >
            <i :class="stats.icon"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="numbers" slot="content">
            <p>{{ stats.title }}</p>
            {{ stats.value }}
          </div>
          <div class="stats" slot="footer">
            <i :class="stats.footerIcon"></i> {{ stats.footerText }}
          </div>
        </stats-card>
      </div>

      <v-button id="click" @click="hideSideBar()" > Hide sideBar  </v-button>
    </div>

    <!--Charts-->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <chart-card
          title="Users behavior"
          sub-title="24 Hours performance"
          :chart-data="usersChart.data"
          :chart-options="usersChart.options"
        >
          <span slot="footer">
            <i class="ti-reload"></i> Updated 3 minutes ago
          </span>
          <div slot="legend">
            <i class="fa fa-circle text-info"></i> Open
            <i class="fa fa-circle text-danger"></i> Click
            <i class="fa fa-circle text-warning"></i> Click Second Time
          </div>
        </chart-card>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
        <chart-card
          title="Email Statistics"
          sub-title="Last campaign performance"
          :chart-data="preferencesChart.data"
          chart-type="Pie"
        >
          <span slot="footer">
            <i class="ti-timer"></i> Campaign set 2 days ago</span
          >
          <div slot="legend">
            <i class="fa fa-circle text-info"></i> Open
            <i class="fa fa-circle text-danger"></i> Bounce
            <i class="fa fa-circle text-warning"></i> Unsubscribe
          </div>
        </chart-card>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
        <chart-card
          title="2015 Sales"
          sub-title="All products including Taxes"
          :chart-data="activityChart.data"
          :chart-options="activityChart.options"
        >
          <span slot="footer">
            <i class="ti-check"></i> Data information certified
          </span>
          <div slot="legend">
            <i class="fa fa-circle text-info"></i> Tesla Model S
            <i class="fa fa-circle text-warning"></i> BMW 5 Series
          </div>
        </chart-card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { StatsCard, ChartCard } from "@/components/index";
import Chartist from "chartist";
export default {
  components: {
    StatsCard,
    ChartCard,
  },
  /**
   * Chart data used to render stats, charts. Should be replaced with server data
   */
  data() {
    return {
      statsCards: [
        {
          type: "warning",
          icon: "ti-server",
          title: "Capacity",
          value: "105GB",
          footerText: "Updated now",
          footerIcon: "ti-reload",
        },
        {
          type: "success",
          icon: "ti-wallet",
          title: "Revenue",
          value: "$1,345",
          footerText: "Last day",
          footerIcon: "ti-calendar",
        },
        {
          type: "danger",
          icon: "ti-pulse",
          title: "Errors",
          value: "23",
          footerText: "In the last hour",
          footerIcon: "ti-timer",
        },
        {
          type: "info",
          icon: "ti-twitter-alt",
          title: "Followers",
          value: "+45",
          footerText: "Updated now",
          footerIcon: "ti-reload",
        },
      ],
      usersChart: {
        data: {
          labels: [
            "9:00AM",
            "12:00AM",
            "3:00PM",
            "6:00PM",
            "9:00PM",
            "12:00PM",
            "3:00AM",
            "6:00AM",
          ],
          series: [
            [287, 385, 490, 562, 594, 626, 698, 895, 952],
            [67, 152, 193, 240, 387, 435, 535, 642, 744],
            [23, 113, 67, 108, 190, 239, 307, 410, 410],
          ],
        },
        options: {
          low: 0,
          high: 1000,
          showArea: true,
          height: "245px",
          axisX: {
            showGrid: false,
          },
          lineSmooth: Chartist.Interpolation.simple({
            divisor: 3,
          }),
          showLine: true,
          showPoint: false,
        },
      },
      activityChart: {
        data: {
          labels: [
            "Jan",
            "Feb",
            "Mar",
            "Apr",
            "Mai",
            "Jun",
            "Jul",
            "Aug",
            "Sep",
            "Oct",
            "Nov",
            "Dec",
          ],
          series: [
            [542, 543, 520, 680, 653, 753, 326, 434, 568, 610, 756, 895],
            [230, 293, 380, 480, 503, 553, 600, 664, 698, 710, 736, 795],
          ],
        },
        options: {
          seriesBarDistance: 10,
          axisX: {
            showGrid: false,
          },
          height: "245px",
        },
      },
      preferencesChart: {
        data: {
          labels: ["62%", "32%", "6%"],
          series: [62, 32, 6],
        },
        options: {},
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>
<style></style>
```

the method shall be declared in /components/SidebarPlugin/SideBar.vue and called in /pages/Dashboard.vue, but I don`t know how to call a method from other .vue Page.

Please Help, what I am doing wrong?

Thank you and Best Regards,

Paul

Comment: You can use an event bus - the calling component will emit an event on the bus and the called component will subscribe for that event on the bus. https://inspector.dev/why-and-how-to-create-an-event-bus-in-vuejs-3/